# How do I fix 'syntax error near unexpected token' when adding Homebrew to my path on Linux using this code?

Tags: bash, syntax-error, homebrew, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I m trying to add homebrew into my path via this code

```
Echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv) "') >> /home/mohit/.profile
```

And getting this error
-bash :syntax error near unexpected token') '

Comment: Is it really "Echo" with capital "E" or did you mean "echo" with lower case "e"?

Comment: The second `)` _is_ wrong. What `(` do you think it should be paired with? -- as excess syntax, this looks to me like a typo-based question.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv) "') >> /home/mohit/.profile
```

but that contains an extra `)`, just after the closing `'`. What you likely want is

```
echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /home/mohit/.profile
```

Note that that will result in the last line of your `.profile` being

```
eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

which may be want you want, or which may contain quotes you don't really need. If you want

```
eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

change the `echo` command to

```
echo 'eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> /home/mohit/.profile
```

Note also that every time you run that `echo`, the line will be added to your `.profile`; if this is something that might happen multiple times, you might want something like

```
profile=/home/mohit/.profile
expression='eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)'
if grep -q "${expression}" "${profile}"; then
    echo No update required
else
    echo "'${expression}'" >> ${profile}
    echo profile updated
fi
```

to make it happen once and only once.